# Bootstrap 3 glyphicons (font-face) causing weird HTML layout issues

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I got a weird problem with bootstrap 3 and the glyphicons!
The problem appears on my android mobile phone with Chrome (latest).

Problem description: If the font-face-statement exists in the bootstrap.css to load the glyphicon font file(s), the layout of the page gets a little bit broken.
On a windows phone, it's fine. It's fine @ Firefox on a Desktop machine too and also in Chrome Desktop.
If I load the page the first time, the layout is OK! If i reload the page or change the page: The weird problem appears and keep! (-> Cache?)

E.g., screenshots from Android Mobile Chrome (latest):

[image] Button group vertical with glypihcons. Icons are moved to the right. (Padding problem?)

[image] Buttons with text @ footer. (Padding problem at right side?)

[image] Label for an input field. (It just breaks)

[image] A self styled Checkbox + Label after it. (Unwanted new line break after the checkbox because the parent container is a lil' bit too small (width)...)

I don't know whats going on! If I remove the font-family for the Glyphicon Icons from bootstrap.css, everything is and keeps okay (insteat the missing glyphicon icons off course). If I let the font-face statement in the file, the problem occurs @ android mobile phone.

Does someone already have had this problemand how can I fix this and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for my self. It don't know what Chrome did, but clearing all the Chrome App Cache worked for me. The Problem was App related.